# How can you limit the number of items one can select using PrimeNG AutoComplete multiple?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

How can you use the AutoComplete component in multi-selection mode but limit the total number of allowed selections to `N` selections

```
<p-autoComplete [multiple]="true"></p-autoComplete>
```

There does not seem to be a way to indicate how many selections you will allow in the autocomplete.  Something like `[limit]="1"` would allow a user to select a maximum of 1 items.

***Does anyone have a workaround for this?***

Answer (score 2):

By Handling the `completeMethod`, check the limit and raise a call to retrieve the remaining data, as below,

```
public filterBrands(event) {
     console.log(event)
     this.filteredBrands = [];
     if (this.brand.length <= 3) {
         for (let i = 0; i < this.brands.length; i++) {
            let brand = this.brands[i];
            if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
             this.filteredBrands.push(brand);
             console.log(this.brand)
         }
     }
 }
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vbJkxVJikTjDuppo7chF?p=preview)